# Why does nothing happen when I hover the menu?

Tags: html, css, hover, display

I want the logo goes away when I hover the menu, but it doesn't work :/. I not that good in Html so I would be pleased if someone could help me:D.

````
    <head>
        <title>
            Test
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id=logo>
                <img src="JRFIilms Logo1.png" alt="logo" height="50px">
            </div>
            <div id=menu>
                <img src="DreiBalkenSchwarz.png" alt="menu" height="50px">
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>```

#menu:hover ~ #logo{
    display:none;
}
````